# Проблема с программным bootloader на stm32f205rg

Tags: boot, stm32

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема с программной прошивкой микроконтроллера stm32f205rg.
Для входа в бутлоадер, который лежит в системной памяти, я использовал функцию boot_softs:

```
void boot_softs() {

volatile uint32_t addr = 0x1FFF0000;
void (*SysMemBootJump)(void);
SysMemBootJump = (void (*)(void)) (*((uint32_t *)(addr + 4)));

HAL_RCC_DeInit();
SysTick->CTRL = 0;
SysTick->LOAD = 0;
SysTick->VAL = 0;
_disable_irq();
SYSCFG->MEMRMP = 0x01;
__set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*)0x20001000);
SysMemBootJump();

}
```

Но почему-то при проверке с помощью программы Flash loader demonstrator, оказывается, что контроллер не вошел с состояние перепрошивки.

Я специально проверил на stm32f207 с таким же кодом и на stm32f103c8 с измененным адресом начала программы и в обоих случаях все работает корректно и контроллер перепрошивается.

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой и может подсказать возможные пути ее решения? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, в системе команд thumb при выполнении команды ветвления `B` нужно указывать адрес функции + 1. То есть `0x1FFF0005`. Второе: почему вы указателю стека присваиваете `0x20001000`? Как я понимаю, вам нужно полностью очистить стек, то есть присвоить ему верхнюю границу оперативной памяти.

Comment: я использовал код из старого видео Calling the STM32 SystemMemory Bootloader from your application, которое лежит на ютюбе и для других контроллеров он работал отлично. нужно было только в зависимости от серии менять адрес начала программы. Но вот почему-то для stm32f205 этот код не сработал и как я его ни крутил, прогресса нет.

Comment: Стало быть, адрес у него отличается. Нужно искать его в документации.